# Does spaces in $xy=1$ have differences between $x y = 1$?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Which way is more correct? I don't see any differences, but maybe I something missed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no difference between the two versions, for readability of the code, `$x y = 1$` is better, however. If you want to some space, use `\,` or `\;` where desired, but this is a matter of taste

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no difference. Let's look at how the output is constructed by adding `\showoutput` and checking the `.log` when compiling the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% To avoid page numbers in the output
\showoutput% Show how the output is constructed
\begin{document}
$xy=1$

$x y = 1$
\end{document}
```

This is extracted from the `.log`:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 525.99937fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 3.55556
...\hbox(6.44444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 300.6899fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon                                       <---------------- mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 y
....\kern0.35878
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\mathoff                                      <---------------- mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.61111
...\hbox(6.44444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 300.6899fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon                                       <---------------- mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 y
....\kern0.35878
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\mathoff                                      <---------------- mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 30.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
```

I've highlighted the important bits above starting with the call `mathon` (called with the processing of the first `$`) and ending with `mathoff` (called with the processing of the final `$`):

```
....\mathon                                       <---------------- mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 y
....\kern0.35878
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\mathoff                                      <---------------- mathoff
```

Both instances are *exactly* the same, implying the output is *exactly* the same. Knuth also mentions this in the [TeXbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (Chapter 16: Typing Math Formulas, p 127):

> Formulas that have been typeset by a printer who is unaccustomed to
>   mathematics usually look quite strange to a mathematician, because a
>   novice printer usually gets the spacing all wrong. In order to alleviate
>   this problem, TeX does most of its own spacing in math formulas; and it
>   *ignores* any spaces that you yourself put between `$`'s. For
>   example, if you type `$ x$` and `$ 2 $`, they will mean the same thing
>   as `$x$` and `$2$`. You can type `(x + y)/(x - y)` or
>   `(x+y) / (x-y)`, but both will result in `$(x+y)/(x-y)$`, a formula in
>   which there is a bit of extra space surrounding the `+` and `-` signs but
>   none around the `/ sign.  Thus, you do not have to memorize the complicated
>   rules of math spacing, and you are free to use blank spaces in any way you
>   like.

Which is best? Make your code readable, so use spaces where necessary.

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference between `$xy=1$` and `$x y = 1$` or `$ x y = 1 $`.
They are rendered the same exactly:

> [image: xy = 1]

The spacing depends on the classification into math atoms:

```
$
\mathord{x}
\mathord{y}
\mathrel{=}
\mathord{1}
$
```

Spacing:

- There is not spacing at the begin or end of the formula except for `\mathsurround`, which is usually 0 pt.
- No space between ordinary math atoms (`\mathord`).
- But as space of `\muskip\thickmuskip` = `\;` is inserted between
  ordinary and relational (`\mathrel`) atoms.

The following example shows the inserted spaces:

```
% plain TeX or LaTeX
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1
\nonstopmode

\setbox0=\hbox{$x y = 1$}
\showbox0

\csname @@end\endcsname\end % end job for plain TeX and LaTeX
```

The result on the console:

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.44444+1.94444)x29.3101
.\mathon
.\teni x
.\teni y
.\kern0.35878
.\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
.\tenrm =
.\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
.\tenrm 1
.\mathoff
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can set both your and Werner's anwsers as solved, but it helps alot!