# Distinguishing a symbol from a character around it while typesetting

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

When typesetting the LaTeX in Math mode is it safe to create a space (one carriage return) around a LaTeX symbol to isolate it from the surrounding character instead of enclosing the surrounding character with {..}. For example if I copy the following [here](http://www.hostmath.com) it displays the same:

```
\hat T \\
\hat{T} \\
\sin x \\
\sin{x} \\
\int f(x)dx \\
\int{f(x)}dx
```

For readability the use of {..} seems a better choice but are there any examples where using the space option will cause an issue? I'm using amsmath package.

Comment: Related: [When one should use spacing like `\quad` or `\,`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25810/5764)

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Do spaces in `$xy=1$` have differences between `$x y = 1$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213873/5764)

Comment: using `{....}` here is wrong and will in general adversely affect the spacing

Comment: I'm interested more in cases where a symbol is defined with alpha characters, e.g. \hat (and not the symbols like ^ or _) and the character that follows is non-numeric. So, for instance, isolating symbol from the character that follows is not an issue for a^2 or \hat2 or \sin2. Hence, in my cases the preferred method would be to use a space and not {..} for isolation, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces (including a single carriage return) are gobbled under math mode. From the [TeX Book](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook), **Chapter 18: Fine Points of Mathematics Typing** (p 166):

> [consider]
>
> ```
> $$ F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}, \qquad n \ge 2. $$
> ```
>
> It is perhaps worth reiterating that TeX ignores all the spaces in math mode
>   (except, of course, the space after `\qquad`, which is needed to distinguish between `\qquad n` and `\qquadn`); so the same result would be obtained if you
>   were to leave out all but one space:
>
> ```
> $$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},\qquad n\ge2.$$
> ```
>
> Whenever you want spacing that differs from the normal conventions, you must
>   specify it explicitly [...].

In fact, it's the preferred method for improving readability, as the use of `{`..`}` may influence the spacing necessarily - changing math elements into a ordinal atom `\mathord`.

So, instead of *grouping* elements to "improve readability", use spaces. Here is an example of using `{`..`}` which causes a problem:

- [{(x+y)}^2 or (x+y)^2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104004/5764)

Comment: After reading yours and David's response, I'm inclined to use spacing over {...}.